# Why I can not change the href value by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code..

```
var content = $("<a href=\"http://www.test.com/test?test1&test2中文\">XXXX</a>");

content.find("a").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', encodeURI(value));
  alert(value);
});​
```

However, it keep showing error.
How can I make this code work which I want to encode the url.

Comment: which error is showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `content.find('a')` use `content.filter('a')`. Because right now you're `content` is an array of only one element (ie. `<a>`), so there is no more `<a>` within that `<a>` and `.find('a')` fails here.

So `.filter()` is safe to use.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0yd9dq/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use **JQuery.find** here as **content** variable has only **anchor** tag and you want to apply **encodeURI** for your URL.

For that requirement below code is well enough.

```
$(content).each(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', encodeURI(value));
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    }
);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: will break when elements other than anchor exists. as pointed in other answer, using filter is safer way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I suggested as there is only href attribute in anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add an ID (if you want to use this for more than one element then create a specific class for the elements and link via `$(".classname")`) to your link and then use a normal query like this

```
var yourLink = $("#yourID");
yourLink.attr('href', encodeURI(value));​
```

and make sure that your `value` has something in it. Also if `.attr(...)` has still no effect please try `.prop("href", encodeURI(value))`